# One Fiber Optic Line 24 Cores for Multiple Services Transmission

Tags: switch, router, fiber

Hello we have a construction project for building a compound of 50+ villas. The aim is build and connect the villas all together transmitting all services through the fiber optic.

The services include:
- TV
- Inter-phone
- Telephone
- Internet (DSL and Cable)
- CCTV Cameras

There will be one main room that includes the main panels and switches of the service then will be transmitted through the fiber optic at each certain point there will be underground pump that will have switchers or extenders to split the services dedicated to each villa. There's one Fiber Optic cable that supports 24 cores.

So what we're gonna do in the main room is insert one switch for DSL internet and one for normal Cable Line Internet, then we'll have multiple TV receivers for different channels, also one central telephony and one Inter-phone cable and for sure the NVR for the Cams. Then from the main Room we should go out with all 5 services to be transmitted through fiber optic to each villa. So each Villa will have TV, Internet (DSL or Cable his choice), Phone Number, Inter-phone and limited CCTV camera access.

Each Villa will have a mechanical room to receive the services through the Fiber Optic line and then split the services accordingly within the whole villa.

My Questions are:

1. Does one cable of Fiber Optic supports all those services passing
   through 24 cores?
2. Do we need signal extender to avoid Fiber delay to far villas from the main room?
3. Is there any certain requirements for Fiber Termination?

Sorry I'm a newbie with Fiber Optic and wanna be sure of my steps.

Comment: This is a bit broad, I'm not sure we can help you with this, but why bother with DSL/Cable Internet when you have Optical Fibers? Just go full fiber.

Comment: @jfl thanks for the comment due that not all local ISPs have Fiber some have Fiber others not it's still in the process therefore the current time we shall stick with what available.

Comment: Removed the request for primarily opinion-based answers.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Does one cable of Fiber Optic supports all those services passing
>   through 24 cores?

Without specific requirements and the specific fiber grade in question, we cannot say for sure, but, in most cases, fiber should be able to handle what you need with a single fiber pair (one for transmit and one for receive, or a single fiber for something like the BX standard) for each location.

> Do we need signal extender to avoid Fiber delay to far villas from the
>   main room?

There really is not a signal extended the way you seem to think. Again, depending on the fiber grade and the specific protocol used, fiber can run for many kilometers.

> Is there any certain requirements for Fiber Termination?

Again, this depends on the fiber-grade used, and it should really be left to a professional to terminate the fiber. The choice of the fiber termination type should be the same as what your equipment uses, but there are fiber patch cables that have different connectors on each end to convert from one type of connector to another. For example, many site have fiber terminated with SC connectors on the fiber patch panel, and that was fine when the equipment usually had SC connectors, so the patch cable was SC-to-SC. Most equipment now comes with LC connectors, so those site get SC-to-LC patch cables. It's no big deal.

---

You question asking for "the best" is off-topic, and I removed it for soliciting primarily opinion-based answers.

> Sorry I'm a newbie with Fiber Optic and wanna be sure of my steps.

In that case, your next step should be to hire a company with certified cable  installers, and I would strongly suggest an RCDD (Registered Communications Distribution Designer) to design it for you. Be sure to communicate that this will involve OSP (Outside Plant) cabling as there are even more regulations and legal liabilities involved, which a lot of installers will not touch. This really is a case of you get what you pay for, and it is not going to be cheap, but you can spend a lot more in the long run with a crap installation using crap parts.